# Indexes mapping from sorted to original array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, indexing

What is an easy way in Java to sort the array of elements maintaining information about indexes where the elements were stored in the original array? Is there a built-in function?

There are few ways I can think of, but none of them is trivial.

1. Implement sort function yourself and return an array of indexes to the original array together with the sorted array.
2. Wrap the elements into a class and store indexes of the original array inside this class, avoiding your sort function.

The reason I need it, is to rearrange the rows in the matrix, when the order of rearrangement is specified by values in the vector. Values in the vector should be in increasing order, and rows in the matrix should be rearranged accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you would be better off creating your own design, maybe create a class called MyDataSorter with a method sort (yourArray) which returns a sorted List of your custom class which could also take generics... something like

`List<OriginalOrderKeeper<MyDataType>> sort (MyDataType [] array)`

Comment: I'm going for a very similar option. Something like IndexedDouble class with 2 fields: double, and index in the original array. Unfortunately a problem with generics is that I would have to specify a concrete type for each simple type array, which explodes number of declarations.

Answer (score 1):

Why not iterating once over the original array before sorting and storing the indexes in a `Map<Object, Integer>`?

Comment: The object is a *double*, and array of doubles needs to be sorted, so you get some boxing, unless some other libraries like *trove* are used which provide maps for simple types. But you still end up creating and maintaining a map.

Comment: @Leonid And why not just copy the original double[] to keep it around?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you could reorder the rows in the matrix directly, you would not need an index.

You can try sorting them using `Arrays.sort(Object[] a, Comparator c)` using a special comparator:

```
public class RowComparator implements Comparator<double[]> {

    public final int columnIndex;

    @Override
    public int compare(double[] row1, double[] row2) {
        return Double.compare(row1[columnIndex], row2[columnIndex]);
    }

    public RowComparator(int columnIndex) {
        super();
        this.columnIndex = columnIndex;
    }

    }
```

You initialize the comparator with the column index relevant for the comparison.

**EDIT**: Rows and columns got mixed up a bit. I assume a double[rows][columns] array.